# Conflict at update/insert on table which has nvarchar indexed relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, relationship

I have tables on sql server like below:

```
:: LG_STATUSES
- code / nvarchar(50)
- name / nvarchar(100)
- description / nvarchar(250)

:: LG_PACKAGES
- LOGICALREF / int
- PersonnelRef / int
- lgStatusCode / nvarchar(50)

// and some other columns which are not related to current problem
```

Lines of Statuses table:

```
code            name            description
------------------------------------------------------------
approved        onaylandı       NULL
draft           taslak          NULL
inApproval      onay sürecinde      NULL
```

When I create relationship between these two tables (Statuses.code & Packages.lgStatusCode) by using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, there is no error. Relationship is created without problem. 
But when I try to insert new lines or update current line on Packages table by changing lgStatusCode

```
UPDATE [dbo].[LG_PACKAGES]
   SET [lgStatusCode] = 'draft'
 WHERE LOGICALREF = 101
```

an error occured like below:

```
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_LG_PACKAGES_LG_STATUSES". The conflict occurred in database "PackageManagement", table "dbo.LG_STATUSES", column 'code'.
```

I couldn't figure out the problem. 'draft' status is also exist in LG_STATUSES table. Does the error occurs because of using string (nvarchar) on relationship? Is this invalid usage?

Thanks.

Edit: SQL Contraint Definition

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LG_PACKAGES]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_LG_PACKAGES_LG_STATUSES] FOREIGN KEY([lgStatusCode])
REFERENCES [dbo].[LG_STATUSES] ([code])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LG_PACKAGES] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LG_PACKAGES_LG_STATUSES]
GO
```

Comment: No obvious reason I can see there can you select from lgstatuses where code = 'draft'? thinking may be 'draft ' or maybe different collations or some such

Comment: That, and 50-character codes seem overly long.  If it's not something like a short ISO code (say, the 3-letter country codes), I'd prefer a numeric code; anything above 10 characters (and anything with accents/non-ASCII-alphanumerics) is probably asking for trouble.

Comment: Perhaps your relationship is created in the wrong direction.  Can you post the SQL constraint definition?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I checked it, same collation for both table and also there isn't any space at codes of statuses.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse You may be right about 50-character long. But numeric code is unpractical for software side of project, in my opinion. That's why I am trying to do so.

Comment: @GordonLinoff SQL Server Management doesn't already allow to build it reverse but I added it question anyway. You can check.

BTW, Thanks for comments.

Comment: @Bilal: SSMS > Databases > open your DB node > Tables > dbo.LG_PACKAGES > Keys > select FK_LG_PACKAGES_LG_STATUSES > open contextul menu (right click) > Script CREATE ...

Comment: @BogdanSahlean I did add it to question text. Is there any mistake with it?

Comment: @Bilal: [1] What is the output of the following SQL statement: `SELECT LEN(code) AS LEN_code, code FROM [dbo].[LG_STATUSES]` ? [2] There are `INSTEAD OF` triggers on `dbo.LG_PACKAGES` table ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean [1] output of sql statement is:
10 approved
7 draft
12 inApproval

[2] There isn't any trigger on LG_PACKAGES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEN(N'draft')` should be 5 not 7 (see above comment). So, very likely you have some spaces in front of `draft` word.

For example, the following statement

```
SELECT LEN(N'  draft') AS L1, LEN(N'draft') AS L2
```

returns:

```
L1          L2
----------- -----------
7           5
```

Above test explain why LEN(code) for draft is 7 instead of 5.

Note: only the spaces situated at the end of the string are insignificant (ex. LEN('draft') = LEN('draft   ') = 5; *this is true for most of collations*). This is behavior according to ANSI SQL standard.

Solution: remove the white spaces situated at the beginning of the `draft` status.

Comment: Not really space but new-line character. Because of the SSMS, I couldn't see them. Most probably when I insert these lines via SSMS I entered instead of moving arrow keys. After I generate script and dump data as insert into, I saw. Thanks!